# Native C Websocket Client

Tags: c, websocket

I have been playing around with writing some code from some lightweight clients and was wondering if there was any good lightweight websocket client that allows connection to secure websockets (wss) for C applications.

Some example code would be great if it existed as well as I am coming from a OOP background which makes it a bit trickey

Comment: I'm told [libwebsockets](https://libwebsockets.org) has a client as well. Barring that, you can find a [decent Websocket parser / formater](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/21af38e894026106efab3992bf4956917fa4e202/lib/facil/http/websocket_parser.h) in the [fail.io](http://facil.io) library. You could also use the library's read/write hooks for TLS/SSL connections, but you'll have to manage handshakes, since it's HTTP and Websocket implementations are server oriented (though the HTTP/1.1 parser supports client side parsing as well).

Answer (score 1):

I'm told [libwebsockets](https://libwebsockets.org) can be used as a client as well.

The [facil.io](http://facil.io) has a simple client (no SSL/TLS)... but you could probably roll your own with [facil.io's parser / formater](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/f31416f6a92e373efb9e63e8eb2f9e7fb56423b2/lib/facil/http/parsers/websocket_parser.h).

You could also use the library's read/write hooks to handle TLS/SSL connections, but you'll have to manage handshakes, since it's HTTP and Websocket implementations are server oriented (though the HTTP/1.1 parser supports client side parsing as well).